# BOSH CLI Expected to find a map at path ... but found '[]interface {}'

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh, bosh

Very similar to another question, but there are slight differences. Tried the accepted answer and still no luck.

I get this error when I run the command:

`bosh -d prometheus deploy -n pfg-prometheus-boshrelease/manifests/prometheus.yml -o replace_vars.yml`

> Expected to find a map at path '/instance_groups/name=prometheus2/jobs/name=prometheus2/properties/prometheus/scrape_configs/job_name=bosh/static_configs/targets?' but found '[]interface {}'

replace_vars.yml:

```
- type: replace
  path: /instance_groups/name=prometheus2/jobs/name=prometheus2/properties/prometheus/scrape_configs/job_name=bosh/static_configs/targets?/-
  value: 192.168.123.26:9190
```

Manifest section:

```
- name: prometheus2
    properties:
      prometheus:
        rule_files:
        - ...
        scrape_configs:
        - file_sd_configs:
          - files:
            - /var/vcap/store/bosh_exporter/bosh_target_groups.json
          job_name: prometheus
          relabel_configs:
          - action: keep
            ...
          - regex: (.*)
            ...
        - job_name: bosh
          scrape_interval: 2m
          scrape_timeout: 1m
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:9190
```

What would the correct path be?

EDIT: I have looked through [bosh cli ops files](https://bosh.io/docs/cli-ops-files/#ops) but cannot find an example like mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also stumpled upon this several times and never found a solution for this use case. What I usually do as a workaround is to replace one step up.
For your example:

`/tmp/replace-vars.yml`:

```
- type: replace
  path: /instance_groups/name=prometheus2/jobs/name=prometheus2/properties/prometheus/scrape_configs/job_name=bosh/static_configs/0
  value:
    targets:
    - 192.168.123.26:9190
    - localhost:9190
```

`/tmp/test-manifest.yml`:

```
instance_groups:
- name: prometheus2
  jobs:
    - name: prometheus2
      properties:
        prometheus:
          rule_files:
          - abc
          scrape_configs:
          - file_sd_configs:
          - files:
            - /var/vcap/store/bosh_exporter/bosh_target_groups.json
          job_name: prometheus
          relabel_configs:
          - action: keep
          - regex: (.*)
          - job_name: bosh
          scrape_interval: 2m
          scrape_timeout: 1m
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - localhost:9190
```

Interpolated by `bosh int /tmp/test-manifest.yml -o /tmp/replace-vars.yml`:

```
instance_groups:
- jobs:
  - name: prometheus2
      properties:
        prometheus:
          rule_files:
          - abc
          scrape_configs:
          - file_sd_configs:
          - files:
            - /var/vcap/store/bosh_exporter/bosh_target_groups.json
          job_name: prometheus
          relabel_configs:
          - action: keep
          - regex: (.*)
          - job_name: bosh
          scrape_interval: 2m
          scrape_timeout: 1m
          static_configs:
          - targets:
            - 192.168.123.26:9190
            - localhost:9190
  name: prometheus2
```